# Spring auto wire bean using java based annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, autowired

I am trying to make a new simple Spring boot application to demo dependency injection. I would like to import beans using @Autowired annotation.

Here is my sample piece of code

----Example.class----

```
package com.example.project;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.*;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Example {


    @Autowired
    public myBean first;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    String home() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Example.class, args);
    }

}
```

----myBean.class----

```
package com.example.project;

public class myBean {

    myBean()
    {
        System.out.println("Hi myBean Constructed");
    }
}
```

---BeanConfiguration.class---

```
package com.example.project;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.project")
public class BeanConfigurationClass {

    @Bean
    public myBean getBean()
    {
        return new myBean();

    }
}
```

--pom.xml---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>example</groupId>
    <artifactId>1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

However when i try to run the application it is unable to find the bean and gives the following error 
Field first in com.example.project.Example required a bean of type 'com.example.project.myBean' that could not be found.

I also tried using xml based configuration but faced the same error.
Is there something fundamentally wrong going over here.

Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: try add public accesser constructor myBean, remove @EnableAutoConfiguration from controller and move BeanConfigurationClass

Answer (score 1):

1. Move `@EnableAutoConfiguration` from controller to your main application class.
2. Get rid of `BeanConfigurationClass`
3. Add one of spring DI class annotations on `myBean` class:

   ```
   @Component
   public class myBean {

       myBean(){
           System.out.println("Hi myBean Constructed");
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: main application class and the controller class are the same . Do i need to have them different . If they are different , I suppose i just need to call controller class object from my main class, please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: This is not valid answer. What do you mean by Get rid of BeanConfigurationClass? Add explainations also for your answers.

Comment: From above approach i get the following error :

Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.

Comment: If you use spring boot, it is good practice to have one main class, where you start it (something like  `public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args) ;}` Controller classes - if  marked with @Controller annotation (or any other inherited) are constructed automatically by spring, ready to use by your RESTful services consumers.

Comment: @TechBreak it means its unnecessary. 
@GauravJuneja paste class where you put `@EnableAutoConfiguration`

Comment: @PiotrSołtysiak it is not unnecessary as this file is annotated with Configuration annotation and it is the main class hence the EAC should be moved on it.

Comment: @PiotrSołtysiak controller annotation automatically doesn't maps my api . 
If i have a main application class as you mentioned the apis are not mapped as the controller is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Name of the classes must starts with CAPITAL letter ! Must be 'My Bean' ..

Answer (score 0):

You should try to do following,

Move `@EnableAutoConfiguration` from controller to your main application class i.e. `BeanConfigurationClass`. This is because `BeanConfigurationClass` is your configuration file and all configurations related annotations should placed on this.

Also rename your `myBean` to `MyBean` and annotate that with `@Component` annotation.

EDIT : Remove following annotations from your `BeanConfigurationClass` and add only this one `@SpringBootApplication` it will take care of all those removed.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
```

Add as ,

```
@SpringBootApplication
BeanConfigurationClass
```

Comment: Hey, I tried but with no luck .
I get the following error :
Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.

Comment: @GauravJuneja make sure you have relevant dependencies added to your build file.

Comment: MyBean method in BeanConfigurationClass should be referred as Bean or component ??
also MyBean.class should be annotated with something??

Comment: I have mentioned that alraedy I suppose? Rename and annotate MyBean with Component and BeanConfigurationClass has already Bean on my bean method.